# Richtextbox scroll position after adding text

Tags: wpf, windows, scroll, wpf-controls, richtextbox

I got a non Web application with a richtextbox and trying to do a lazy load implementation that when I got to the end of the scroll new information is added. The problem is that after I append the new information on the bottom of the scroll instead of the scroll being adjusted it scrolls all the way up. Do I have some way of adjust the scroll or jump to the last visible line so the user does not realize that there was a refresh on the richtextbox? I tried to cache the vertical scroll position before the new information is added and set it after, but for some reason, as I am doing this when the scroll is at the bottom, new "old" vertical position is the same as the "new" bottom of the scroll.

Does anyone has a clue of what can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RichText.AppendText(text);
RichText.ScrollToEnd();
```

Comment: Ok, I forgot to explain one thing... I got two elements with a scrollbar... an ultragrid and a richtextbox...and when the ultragrid scroll is at bottom more elements are added to it and to the richtextbox... and if the user has scrolled the richtextbox I want it to conserve the information that was being viewed before the new information.